# Unable to run a test from MTM - Config issue

Tags: selenium, tfs, mstest, mtm

I have set up a Test Controller and Test Agent running in separate machines and they are able to communicate with each other.

When I try to run the test from MTM (Selenium Tests), the test failed with the below error message

```
(QTController.exe, PID 1104, Thread 15) Could not use lab service account to access the build directory. 
Failure: Network path does not exist or is not accesible using following user:
https://mydevelopment.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/c2f372df-8c45-487a-9b51-4ced6e8f6037/_apis/build/builds/969/artifacts?artifactName=drop&%24format=zip 
using MYDEV\timothy.alex. Error Code: 67

(QTController.exe, PID 1104, Thread 15) TcmRunner: Error starting the test run: The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required..
```

This clearly mentions that the error is because of access issue. But when I try downloading the build from the url mentioned in the error log using the same credentials mentioned in the ERROR log, I am able to download the drop zip file.

Is there any thing I am missing in the set up. Any help would be really really great.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your settings for Test Controller?

Comment: Are you using XAML build or the newer build system?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the new task-based build system. You can't run automated tests from a task-based build from MTM at present -- you have to use the older XAML build system for that.